# Is there a way to extract just the decimal value from django-money MoneyField without currency value?

Tags: django

I want to extract just the decimal value from the MoneyField value. Right now the value of the field renders as something like US$1.00, but this isn't ideal when just the decimal value is required for use. I get an error message like ["'US$1.00' value must be a decimal number."]

Comment: Yes, with `object.field.amount`, or thus `.amount` of the `Money` object.

Comment: Awesome thanks Willem. I thought I had tried that, but guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's `MoneyField` uses the `Money` class of the [**`py-moneyed`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed) as the "Python side" of the data.

This [**`Money`** class [GitHub]](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed/blob/master/moneyed/classes.py#L73) has basically two attributes: `amount`, and `currency`.

So if you have `Money` object, you can retrieve the `.amount` object, as is demonstrated on the GitHub page:

> ```
> >>> from moneyed import Money, USD
> >>> price = Money('19.50', USD)
> >>> price
> 19 USD
>
> >>> price.amount
> Decimal('19.50')
>
> >>> price.currency
> USD
>
> >>> price.currency.code
> 'USD'
> ```

You can thus create `Money` objects by calling the constructor, and retrieve the attributes to do indivual process of the amount and the currency.

Comment: Do you happen to also know how to get just the $? I've tried prefix, symbol, and sign.

Comment: @Whodini: it is the next section on the GitHub page https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed#formatting :)

Comment: or in other words just render $1.00 instead of US$1.00?

Comment: import `from moneyed.localization import format_money`, and render it with `format_money(money, locale='en_US')`.